# How can I geocode two addresses without using the Google Maps API geocoder

Tags: php, python, google-maps

I need to measure distance between 100 Addresses and i have the feeling the the Google-API is an overkill for that. Especially all the authorization stuff.

Is there another way / service to calculate distances, without needing heavy setup? Just a HTML-Request with a JSON as a Response?

Comment: What authorization "stuff"?

Comment: For example the API Key or the reason, that you have to use the google api library.

Comment: Its ridiculous to define this as a duplicate, i am asking about a service, not the mathematical term to calculate distance between two lat long values.

Comment: You've asked for another service **or** another way, calculating is another way. When you ask for another service the question is offtopic and may be closed too, because SO is about coding, not about suggesting ressources.

Comment: I can pull out at minimum 100 Threads which are not directly related to code in SO but are one of the most visited ones. However, do what you think is right.